# Why all content of image is not displayed completely

Tags: flutter, image, dart, flutter-dependencies

Why the content of image is not completely displayed [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZmk8.jpg)
If I remove ,fit: BoxFit.cover, Then it display all content but create extra space above Which I can't created.
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOm2L.jpg)

```
  Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: ClipRRect(
             child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child:  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(image),fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),

              ),
            )
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
Expanded(
  flex: 5,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1/1, // Replace with the aspect ratio of your image
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage(image),
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: it create extra space as I have send screenshot above (image2) .